# Firebase Database Snapshot ForEach Async Await

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

async/await doesn't seem to work with firebase forEach. This code runs console.log for the first child of the snapshot and then just hangs. Is this a bug or am I missing something?

```
main()
async function main() {
  const snap = await root.ref('somepath')
    .once('value')

  snap.forEach(async val => {
    await console.log(val.key)

  })
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's an unintentional consequence of a feature, sometimes knows as a bug. From the firebase documentation:
[image: Firebase documentation]

an `async` function always returns a Promise. And a promise is true-y value:

`!!Promise.resolve===true`.

As a workaround, try this solution:

```
main()
async function main() {
  const snap = await root.ref('somepath')
    .once('value')

  snap.forEach(function wrapper(){async val => {
    await console.log(val.key)
  }})
```

It won't wait for the promise to complete before moving to the next snapshot though. That would require a bit more code, but that may not be what you need anyways.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Great explanation. I think the firebase documentation is pretty good. Surprised I missed that.

I saw this right after you posted it. Was just slow with this response ;)

Comment: thanks - spent so long trying to figure this out. I tried the § for (child in snapshot) § approach but snapshots aren't interable so this answer should help

Comment: "It won't wait for the promise to complete before moving to the next snapshot though."  - but isn't that the whole point of "await"? so that we can let some code complete before moving onto the next bit of code/snapshot?

Comment: @Davie, this depends on your usecase. You might just need a bunch sequential await done for each item, but overlapping different items at once

Answer (score 5):

I use something like this:

```
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";

type FunctionOnDataSnapshot = (childSnapshot: admin.database.DataSnapshot) => Promise<any>;
export const asyncForEach = async (dataSnapshot: admin.database.DataSnapshot, childFunction: FunctionOnDataSnapshot) => {
    const toWait = [];
    dataSnapshot.forEach(childSnapshot => {
        toWait.push(childFunction((childSnapshot)));
    });
    await Promise.all(toWait);
};
```